# How do I check State Code if it has four characters and then transform it to 2 character code?

Tags: xml, xslt

What I am trying to do is check in the XML document for the element

`<DriversLicenseState Word="CDON">Ontario</DriversLicenseState>`.

If State code found is four characters and begins with ‘CD’ only display the last two characters. In this case (example) I would display  `<nc:JurisdictionCanadianProvinceCode>ON</nc:JurisdictionCanadianProvinceCode>`

I am not sure how to add logic to do this.

**XML document**

```
<Integration xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" xmlns:tsg="http://tsgweb.com" xmlns:IXML="http://tsgweb.com" xmlns:CMCodeQueryHelper="urn:CMCodeQueryHelper" PackageID="IXML Case Notification Test" MessageID="67077793" xmlns="">
    <Party ID="8265760" InternalPartyID="392728694">
        <PartyName ID="4614549" Current="true" InternalNameID="1612416995">
            <NameType>Standard</NameType>
            <NameFirst>Ismael</NameFirst>
            <NameLast>Montemayor-Lira</NameLast>
            <FormattedName>Montemayor-Lira, Ismael</FormattedName>
        </PartyName>
        <DriversLicense Current="true">
            <DriversLicenseNumber>321456782541A</DriversLicenseNumber>
            <DriversLicenseState Word="CDON">Ontario</DriversLicenseState>
        </DriversLicense>
     </Party>
</Integration>
```

**XSLT**

```
<xsl:template name="ChargeDetails">
  <nc:IdentificationJurisdiction>
    <nc:JurisdictionCanadianProvinceCode>
        <xsl:for-each select="/Integration/Party/DriversLicense[@current='true']/DriversLicenseState">
            <xsl:if test="/Integration/Party/DriversLicense[@current='true']/DriversLicenseState[@Word]">
            <xsl:value-of select="substring(/Integration/Party/DriversLicense[@Current='true']/DriversLicenseState/@Word, 1, 2)"/>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </nc:JurisdictionCanadianProvinceCode>
  </nc:IdentificationJurisdiction>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: What programming language?  Where do you want to display results?

Comment: I am using xslt to display the <nc:JurisdictionCanadianProvinceCode>ON</nc:JurisdictionCanadianProvinceCode>. I have added my xslt code but it is not displaying anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code uses the wrong XPATH expressions, I suppose. In addition, the attribute `@current` is written `Current` in your XML.

Providing the XPATH expression in your `xsl:for-each` is ok, the following code snippet should display the desired result:

```
<xsl:template name="ChargeDetails">
  <nc:IdentificationJurisdiction>
     <nc:JurisdictionCanadianProvinceCode>
        <xsl:for-each select="/Integration/Party/DriversLicense[@Current='true']">
           <xsl:if test="DriversLicenseState[string-length(@Word) = 4 and substring(@Word,1,2) = 'CD']">
              <xsl:value-of select="substring(DriversLicenseState/@Word, 3, 2)"/>
           </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
     </nc:JurisdictionCanadianProvinceCode>
  </nc:IdentificationJurisdiction>
</xsl:template>
```

Calling `xsl:for-each` inside the destination element sounds a bit strange. Maybe you want to interchange them.

Comment: Thanks leu. This is now working as needed. Awesome! I did change the code `xsl:for-each` and placed it outside the `<nc:JurisdictionCanadianProvinceCode>`